# How can I make a URL link in django that will go to the referring view?

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to create a back link to the referring URL, if the referrer was a view, and if it was not a view, a back link to a default page (Don't ask... it's kind of a weird requirement).

Basically, if the user came to the page in question from another view on the same django site, the back link should be a return to that view.

If the user came in from an external site, the back link should go to a default view.

Javascript is not an ideal solution, although I'm willing to consider it if there's no other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`django.core.urlresolvers.resolve`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve) to figure out if it's an internal Django URL or not. If it is not, it will raise `django.core.urlresolvers.Resolver404`, otherwise it will return a match object you can introspect if necessary. You can feed the `REFERER` environment variable to this as necessary, and replace the URL with a default URL if `resolve` raises Resolver404.

**edit**: Actually, no, `resolve` apparently only works with path components of URLs. So you'd have to deconstruct the `REFERER` header using [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) to figure out if it's the right domain, and if it is, use `resolve` on the path component of the parsed URL to figure out if the URL is part of your Django site or not.

```
# code not tested, YMMV, etc. 

from urlparse import urlparse

from django.core import urlresolvers

HOME = 'http://my.site.com/'

def generate_back_url(url, default_url=HOME):
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    if parsed.netloc == 'my.site.com':
        try:
            urlresolvers.resolve(parsed.path)
        except urlresolvers.Resolver404:
            back_url = default_url
        else:
            back_url = url
    else:
        back_url = default_url
    return back_url

# ...

def my_view(request):
    # ...
    # truth be told I'm not sure whether the .get() is necessary, sorry.
    back_url = generate_back_url(request.META.get('REFERER', HOME))
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `django.utils.http.is_safe_url()` instead.

```
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url

def my_view(request):
    # ...
    if is_safe_url(url=url, host=request.get_host()):
        back_url = url
    else:
        back_url = default_url
```